# QML and webassembly

Tags: qml, webassembly, qt-quick

I have a python-qml app and I uploaded qml files in https://qt-webassembly.io/designviewer/.
The app works, how can I get the webassembly code to put it in my site-app?

**Update:**

In MaintenanceTool I see this:

[image]

In QCreator (with c++ project and qml)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that site compiles and runs QML in the browser directly. Meaning it doesn't support what you want to use it for.

Seems like you'd have better luck using the Qt Creator IDE targeting Web Assembly.

https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-setup-webassembly.html

Comment: Thank you, I have python-qml app and I have no weassempbly target. Maybe I must create c++ project and insert the qml files. I suppose that with webassembly c++ or pyhton doesn't make the difference because is only used qml, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Qt Web Assembly uses enscripten which compiles C++ to Web Assembly. You should be able to create a blank QML app in Creator and then just drop in all of your QML inside of it and then target Web Assembly.

Comment: I saw that I can't target in webassembly. I must download a plugin of QCreator?

Comment: Easiest thing to do is go to qt.io and download the free version of Qt from there. It will contain Creator and the full toolchain for WebAssembly (if you select it in the installer).

Comment: Did you check all of the settings are correct as described at the link in my answer?

Comment: I didn't have "emscripten tool chain for compiling to WebAssembly". I download that and I'll try. Thank you.